# Adding parameters to SQLCommand and adding value later

Tags: powershell, parameters, sqlcommand

I've seen the different discussions of using `Parameters.Add` vs `Parameters.AddWithValue` (one is explicit, the other is not), but that isn't my issue.

I'm defining a command, which will be used to do multiple inserts into the database. I figured I'd do something like the following:

```
[define command]
[add parameters (including a batchid not known at this time)]

[enter loop]
   [create new batchid]
   [set parameter value]
   [execute command]
[next]
```

This would mean my parameters are neatly defined in advance, and I set their values within the loop. The code for that looks like this:

```
$SqlCmdAdd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmdAdd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SqlCmdAdd.CommandText = "AddBatch"
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@RunId", [Data.SQLDBType]::UniqueIdentifier)
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@RunType", [Data.SQLDBType]::NVarChar, 50)
$SqlCmdAdd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

Within the loop I figured I could do something like this:

```
# Generate GUID to be used as a BatchID
$batchID = [guid]::NewGuid()

# I tried both using the parameter name, as well as their numeric order. Neither worked
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters["@RunId"].Value = $batchID | Out-Null
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters["@RunType"].Value = "HDD" | Out-Null
# $SqlCmdAdd.Parameters[0].SqlValue = $batchID | Out-Null
# $SqlCmdAdd.Parameters[1].SqlValue = "HDD" | Out-Null
```

However, if I read out the values of $SqlCmdAdd.Parameters[0] and [1], I see the proper names and data types, but their values are null. Thus, I'll get an error that no values were specified for the parameters.

What did work was:

```
$SqlCmdAdd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmdAdd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
$SqlCmdAdd.CommandText = "AddBatch"
$SqlCmdAdd.Connection = $SqlConnection
```

Within the loop doing this:

```
# Add parameters
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunId", $batchID) | Out-Null
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RunType", "HDD") | Out-Null
$SqlCmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
$SqlConnection.Close()

# Clear parameter collection for next run
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters.Clear()
```

What irritates me about this is the need to clear the parameter collection for the next run, and then recreating them. While that runs my code, I'm interested in finding out why attempting to set the value of the earlier created parameters in the first code block doesn't have any effect.

I tried googling and read countless articles.

Comment: Try and remove ` | Out-Null` from assingment statements: `...Value = $batchID`

Comment: @vonPryz I'll be damned. I added them because earlier things weren't working, and I saw a ton of other articles defining them as such. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it and get you some extra points :)

Comment: Just saying thanks, many links out there about how to *generally* write this in powershell (or just C# lite) don't work...

Comment: Thanks -- this helped me: $SqlCmdAdd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]::StoredProcedure
Couldn't find how to set the SqlCmd commandType elsewhere.
Now I can see how to use C# namespaces to get to types in powershell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens, as piping the variable to `Out-Null` happens before assignment. Thus,

```
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters["@RunId"].Value = $batchID | Out-Null
```

Will first pass `$batchID` to `Out-Null`, and the result - `$null` - is assigned into `.Value`.

As for a fix, just remove `Out-Null` like so,

```
$SqlCmdAdd.Parameters["@RunId"].Value = $batchID
```

Comment: Thanks you, especially for explaining *why* my original code didn't work.